# Error import hdf5 file to train hdf5_classification in caffe

Tags: c++, caffe, hdf5

This is my log

```
Log file created at: 2016/04/29 14:01:52
    Running on machine: DELL
    Log line format: [IWEF]mmdd hh:mm:ss.uuuuuu threadid file:line] msg
    F0429 14:01:52.191473 14832 upgrade_proto.cpp:79] Check failed: ReadProtoFromTextFile(param_file, param) Failed to parse NetParameter file: examples/hdf5_classification/nonlinear_auto_train.prototxt
```

This is my bat

```
.\bin\caffe.exe train --solver=D:\caffe-windows-master\examples\hdf5_classification\nonlinear_solver.prototxt
pause
```

This is my nonlinear_solver.prototxt

```
train_net: "examples/hdf5_classification/nonlinear_auto_train.prototxt"
#test_net: "examples/hdf5_classification/nonlinear_auto_test.prototxt"
#test_iter: 250
#test_interval: 1000
base_lr: 0.01
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1
stepsize: 5000
display: 1000
max_iter: 10000
momentum: 0.9
weight_decay: 0.0005
snapshot: 10000
snapshot_prefix: "examples/hdf5_classification/data/train"
solver_mode: GPU
```

This is my nonlinear_auto_train.prototxt

```
layer {
  name: "data"
  type: "HDF5Data"
  top: "data"
  top: "label"
  hdf5_data_param {
    source: "D:\caffe-windows-master\examples/hdf5_classification/data/list.txt"
    batch_size: 10
  }
}
layer {
  name: "ip1"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "ip1"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 40
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "relu1"
  type: "ReLU"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip1"
}
layer {
  name: "ip2"
  type: "InnerProduct"
  bottom: "ip1"
  top: "ip2"
  inner_product_param {
    num_output: 2
    weight_filler {
      type: "xavier"
    }
  }
}
layer {
  name: "accuracy"
  type: "Accuracy"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "accuracy"
}
layer {
  name: "loss"
  type: "SoftmaxWithLoss"
  bottom: "ip2"
  bottom: "label"
  top: "loss"
}
```

the code runs on the windows

> Firstly, I can't find the D:\ThirdPartyLibrary;
>
> Secondly, the h5 file has been saved in proper folder;
>
> Thirdly, I use the absolute path for every file

I don't know why the code doesn't run well

Comment: Copy paste the log here instead of using an image. Also give more information, by sharing the edits you made in the prototxt file to understand the real issue

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I have changed the describition.

Comment: Shouldn't it be forwardslash '/' instead of backslash '\' in the value of 'train_net' in nonlinear_solver.prototxt

Comment: I changed it as you said, but it is still in the same wrong situation.

Answer (score 0):

You got an error message "failed to parse [...]train.prototxt".
This hints that you have a syntax error in your train.prototxt file.
I would suspect the line

> ```
> source: "D:\caffe-windows-master\examples/hdf5_classification/data/list.txt"
> ```

as it mixes slashes and backslashes.
Try:

```
source: "D:/caffe-windows-master/examples/hdf5_classification/data/list.txt"
```